# Get max record for each group of records, link multiple tables

Tags: sql, postgresql

I seek to find the maximum timestamp (ob.create_ts) for each group of marketid's (ob.marketid), joining tables obe (ob.orderbookid = obe.orderbookid) and market (ob.marketid = m.marketid). Although there are a number of solutions posted like this for a single table, when I join multiple tables, I get redundant results. Sample table and desired results below:

### table: ob

| orderbookid | marketid | create_ts |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | 1664635255298 |
| 2 | 1 | 1664635255299 |
| 3 | 1 | 1664635255300 |
| 4 | 2 | 1664635255301 |
| 5 | 2 | 1664635255302 |
| 6 | 2 | 1664635255303 |

### table: obe

| orderbookentryid | orderbookid | entryname |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | 'entry-1' |
| 2 | 1 | 'entry-2' |
| 3 | 1 | 'entry-3' |
| 4 | 2 | 'entry-4' |
| 5 | 2 | 'entry-5' |
| 6 | 3 | 'entry-6' |
| 7 | 3 | 'entry-7' |
| 8 | 4 | 'entry-8' |
| 9 | 5 | 'entry-9' |
| 10 | 6 | 'entry-10' |

### table: m

| marketid | marketname |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 'market-1' |
| 2 | 'market-2' |

### desired results

| ob.orderbookid | ob.marketid | obe.orderbookentryid | obe.entryname | m.marketname |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 3 | 1 | 6 | 'entry-6' | 'market-1' |
| 3 | 1 | 7 | 'entry-7' | 'market-1' |
| 6 | 2 | 10 | 'entry-10' | 'market-2' |

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `ROW_NUMBER()` to get a properly filtered `ob` table. Then `JOIN` the other tables onto that!

```
WITH
    ob_filtered AS (
        SELECT
            orderbookid,
            marketid
        FROM
            (
            SELECT
                *,
                ROW_NUMBER() OVER (
                    PARTITION BY
                        marketid
                    ORDER BY
                        create_ts DESC
                ) AS create_ts_rownumber
            FROM
                ob
            ) ob_with_rownumber
        WHERE
            create_ts_rownumber = 1
        )

SELECT
    ob_filtered.orderbookid,
    ob_filtered.marketid,
    obe.orderbookentryid,
    obe.entryname,
    m.marketname
FROM
    ob_filtered
    JOIN m 
        ON m.marketid = ob_filtered.marketid
    JOIN obe 
        ON ob_filtered.orderbookid = obe.orderbookid
;
```